# api-ms-win-core-libraryloader_l1-2-0.dll on windows vista

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have not enough knowledge on how to fix this. What I do know is:

- Build a Executable in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8.1 (hence the 1-2-0.dll)
- Running the executable, crashes on Windows Vista with the message: "This application could not be started, because of the api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll"
- Under vista you would have the libraryloader 1-1-0 if not mistaken?
- this library is linked from mscorlib.dll somehow? But not referencing this dll would not build the project.

Maybe someone could direct me in correct way? Or better have a solution for this?

Is there a way to tell VS to not use this latest dll version?
I am certain I did not reference this specific DLL.

Comment: You copied a Windows DLL as well, one that can only run on Windows 8.1.  One of the DirectX dlls are the typical cause, especially d3dcompiler_47.dll.  You have to use the redist version you find back in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Redist\D3D\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem, in my case I was providing the d3d9.dll and d3d11.dll, that I copied from windows 8.1 windows instalation directory and ofc. I cant use those!

And then all Computers like Vista, Windows 7 and even Windows 8 had that Error:

"This application could not be started, because of the api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll"

Because this file:
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll belongs to Windows 8.1

Solution?
In my instaler, Installshield, I removed the d3d9.dll and d3d11.dll, so my aplication will use the ones already in OS.
The problem was not in the "EXE" produced by Visual Studio, but in DLL dependecies that I was providing.

Comment: It was indeed with the dependencies provided.
I eventually build it on another machine and got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

this problem occurred due to Compatibility with older operating systems.
this link may help you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh802935(v=vs.85).aspx